# Android set style in constructor

Tags: android, coding-style, constructor

I am creating UI dynamically in my code. I know it's impossible to switch between styles via code at runtime, but how can I assign the style while creating object?

I want to use something like:

```
 ListView listView = new ListView(this, null, R.style.listViewStyle);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible. The closest solution is to create an XML file describing the ListView and then just inflate a View.

Comment: Why is it not possible? What's the use of the third parameter in the constructor?

Comment: None. It's bugged and it doesn't work. Quite normal on Android.